# Java. Could not find or load main class

Tags: java

I know this has been asked before...Just none of the answers on other questions worked.
When I try to run this in eclipse I just get `Error: Could not find or load main class Hey.Init` in the console. "Hey" is the package.

I can post the third class I just don't think it's relevant.

```
package Hey;

import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Init {
    static Runnable createGui = new Runnable(){
        public void run(){
            new Gui();
        }
    };
    public static void main(String[] args){
         SwingUtilities.invokeLater(createGui);
   }
}
```

Other Class:

```
package Hey;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;


import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;


public class Gui  { 
    private JFrame frame = new JFrame("Title");
    private JButton button;
    public Gui(){
        frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        button = new JButton("DON'T HIT ME!!!");
        button.addMouseListener(new Yo());
    }
}
```

Comment: This means the class has not been compiled.  I don't know why eclipse hasn't compiled the class before attempting to execute it.

Comment: So what can I do to fix this?

Comment: I don't use eclipse, I use IntelliJ so all I can suggest is to use the latter.  I am sure there is an option which has been set incorrectly for the "build and run", but I don't know what it is.

Comment: I happen to have intelliJ in stalled. I will try to run it with that.

Comment: Don't run your swing gui in the main thread, this can cause problems. Instead use `SwingUtilities.invokeLater`.

Comment: Okay I'm now using invokeLater and IntelliJ. But nothing happens when I run the code. There is no errors.

Comment: Find a tutorial. Get it working for you. Then adapt it to solve your problem.

Comment: You are not showing the Frame or adding the button to it.

Answer (score 0):

Weird as i do not see any issue in here. However it could be that you are trying to run a file which is not set as "main project" and effectively may not have a main method, if you know what i mean. Also on the side note

```
    @Override
    public void run(){
        Gui gui = new Gui();
    }
```

And one more thing why not implement the interface ?

```
public class Hello implements Runnable{ 
      ....
}
```